# How to access raw json payload from remote service in Ember when using Ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember 2 and Ember-data 2 and trying to access the raw json payload the standard RESTAdapter fetches from my REST Api and keeps in store. Can't find anything regarding this in the documentation or elsewhere. Is the only option to create a custom RESTAdapter?

Comment: Why do you want that, for debugging purposes? Because you could easily debug this in chrome developer tools by looking at your network tab.

Comment: I have a view in a CMS interface where I'd like to display the content in json in addition to what I get from Ember model. There are some metadata  which is not mapped to Ember model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I would do it is to add a separate property to your model, then override your serializer.

First your model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

    rawJSON: DS.attr()

    // Your other attributes...
});
```

Your serializer (I'm using the JSONSerializer as an example, but other serializers should be fairly similar):

```
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    normalize(typeClass) {
        // Simulate the extra attribute by adding it to the hash
        hash.rawJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
        // Then let the serializer do the rest
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    serialize(snapshot, options) {
        // Let the serializer create the JSON
        const json = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        // Remove the extra attribute we added
        delete json.rawJSON;

        return json;
    }
});
```

You can choose to do this for all of your models by overridding the application serializer, or just a particular model by overriding the serializer for just that type.